# Android & Robotium - Test activity that expects an extra?

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium

It seems to me that robotium was designed in a way to test 1 Activity at a time instead of the whole application.

So my question is how do I test an activity that expects an extra to be passed to it?
by extra I mean `intent.putExtra("Something", object);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method **setActivityIntent(Intent)** should be what you are looking for. I used this method to provide a custom Intent to my Activity's TestCase. Just use it after you call **super** in your constructor.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("myExtra", "anyValue");
setActivityIntent(i);
```

You don't have to do it in the constructor i think, but you need to make sure that you call it **before you call getActivity()** for the first time. getActivity will use your Intent to create the Activity.

Comment: Actually in last version of Robotium we should setActivityIntent() in setup() before getActivty()

Answer (score 4):

You could override getActivity() instead.

```
@Override
public NewActivity getActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("exampleExtra", "some data");
    setActivityIntent(intent);
    return super.getActivity();
}
```

See [Testing for Android with Robotium](http://blog.shinetech.com/2012/09/05/testing-for-android-with-robotium/) for more details.